# JQuery replaceWith one HTML tag with another

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `img` tab as below:

```
  <img class="media-1200px" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
```

I use .replaceWith() `$(this).replaceWith("<div>" + $(this).html() + "</div>");`  and expect a code like below:

```
  <div class="media-1200px" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" </div>
```

But somehow I got:

```
<div></div>
```

Please take a look at my code:

```js
$('img').each(function() {
  $(this).replaceWith("<div>" + $(this).html() + "</div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="media-1200px" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
```

Comment: `$(this).html()` only returns the HTML nested inside the element, not the element itself.

Comment: Your desired result isn't even valid. `div` doesn't have `src` attribute.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want `<div><img></div>`? You would use `.wrap()` for this.

Comment: Hi Barmar, Thanks for your concern!  Yes, I know that div doesn't have src attribute, but I want to get `<img` out and replace with `<div>`.  Then I will remove `src`, as well.  Please take a look at my update here https://jsfiddle.net/of56k3p8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `.html()` to get the HTML of the element itself. And even if you could, since you're putting the HTML between `<div>` and `</div>`, it would nest the image inside the DIV (like `.wrap()` does) rather than put the image attributes into the DIV itself.

You'll need to create the DIV element and copy the attributes to it.

```js
$('img').replaceWith(function() {
  return $("<div>", {
    "class": $(this).attr("class"),
    css: {
      "background-image": `url(${$(this).attr("src")})`
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div.media-1200px {
  width: 1200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="media-1200px" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
```

Comment: Thanks, Barmar for pointing out my issue and yes code works as expected!

Answer (score 1):

### DOM NODE REPLACEMENT APPROACH:

With vanilla JavaScript, you can just use the [outerHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) attribute to retrieve the element as a string and just replace "img" with "div" using the [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method and then replace the `<img>` element with your `<div>` in your DOM (not really sure why since div can't really utilise the `src` attribute) by just converting your current retrieved string assigned to the `div` variable to a DOM Node using the [createContextualFragment()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) and then using the [replaceNode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild) method to replace the `img` node with the `div` node in your DOM.

Check and run the following Code Snippet or open this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL64/504xh82r/28/) for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
const div = img.outerHTML.replace("img", "div");
let newDiv = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(div);

img.parentNode.replaceChild(newDiv, img);
```

```html
 <img class="media-1200px" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
```

**N.B.** You will have to inspect the Code Snippet sandbox or the JSFiddle sandbox to see the `<img/>` element replaced with the `<div>` element.

---

### CLONING ATTRIBUTES APPROACH:

Another way to do this (got this idea from Barmar's jQuery solution above) would be to create a new div element and just cloning the attributes from the `<img>` element to the new `<div>` element using the [attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) property and [setAttributes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method like this:

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img");
const newDiv = document.createElement("div");

[...img.attributes].forEach(({name, value}) =>
  newDiv.setAttribute(name, value)
);

img.parentNode.replaceChild(newDiv, img);
```

```html
<img class="media-1200px" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414612/pexels-photo-414612.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500">
```

**N.B.** Again, you will have to inspect the Code Snippet sandbox or the JSFiddle sandbox to see the `<img/>` element replaced with the `<div>` element.

Comment: Thanks, Andrew for showing another solution!  and yes, the code shows as expected in inspector.

Comment: @abcidd Glad I could help!! Do check out the alternate approach that I just added which is more or less a pure JavaScript version of Barmar's answer too.

Answer (score 0):

try with this

```
    $('img').each(function() {
            $(this).replaceWith("<div with="100px"> + $(this).html() + "</div>"); 
});
```

you should set attribute width to visualize a div.

Comment: Is `with` a typo for `width`? How will this solve the problem of the missing `src` and `class` attributes?

Comment: Because $(this).html() have the img html, then he is putting the img html into div

Comment: `$(this).html()` doesn't have the image HTML. `.html()` returns the HTML of nested elements, not the element itself. That's the `.outerHTML` property, which has no jQuery equivalent.

Comment: Except for the `with` attribute this is the same as the OP's code, and he doesn't get the image HTML.

Comment: can you create a stack snippet that demonstrates it?